# The semi-empirical mass formula

Tags: python, physics

my homework says the following:

[image: Exercise]

Up until c) my code works, I've tried with different values of Z. Here's my code:

```
# This program calculates the mass number for which the binding energy per nucleon is max for a given atomic number. 
import math
from math import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
# First we define some variables
a_1 = 15.67
a_2 = 17.23
a_3 = 0.75
a_4 = 93.2
# We ask for input Z
Z = float(input("Enter the atomic number: "))
list_B = []
list_A = []
list_B_A = []
# We set up the loop
for A in arange(Z,3*Z+1): #we make A run from Z to 3Z
    list_A.append(A)
        if (A%2)==0:
            if ((A+Z)%2)==0:
                a_5 = 12.0
            else:
                a_5 = -12.0
        else:
            a_5 = 0
        B = a_1*A - a_2*(A**(2/3)) - a_3*(Z**2)/(A**(1/3)) - a_4*((A-2*Z)**2)/A + a_5/(A**(1/2))
        B_A = B/A #We print the resulting value of B
        list_B.append(B)
        list_B_A.append(B/A) #We make a list with this values


print("The Mass number for the maximum binding energy is: ",list_A[list_B_A.index(max(list_B_A))])
```

Now, when I try to do d) it doesn't work and for values bigger than z= 24 it always gives A max = 50 which is not what the first code gives me.
For example, when I run the code for c) Z=28 gives me A max =58. But when I run the code for d) once Z reaches 24 it always returns 50.

```
import math
from math import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
# First we define some variables
a_1 = 15.67
a_2 = 17.23
a_3 = 0.75
a_4 = 93.2
# We ask for input Z
list_B = []
list_A = []
list_B_A = []

for Z in arange(1,101,1):
    for A in arange(Z,3*Z+1): #we make A run from Z to 3Z
        list_A.append(A)
        if (A%2)==0:
            if ((A+Z)%2)==0:
                a_5 = 12.0
            else:
                a_5 = -12.0
        else:
            a_5 = 0
        B = a_1*A - a_2*(A**(2/3)) - a_3*(Z**2)/(A**(1/3)) - a_4*((A-2*Z)**2)/A + a_5/(A**(1/2))
        B_A = B/A #We print the resulting value of B
        list_B.append(B)
        list_B_A.append(B/A) #We make a list with this values
    print("The Mass number for the maximum binding energy is: ",list_A[list_B_A.index(max(list_B_A))], "given the atomic number :", Z)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-initialize  all the lists before redoing the calculation with a new `Z` value. Otherwise you're combining the data for this `Z` with all the previous ones.

```
for Z in arange(1,101,1):
    list_B = []
    list_A = []
    list_B_A = []
    # rest of your code here
```